# installing loadrunner on linux

Tags: linux, loadrunner, vmware-workstation

i have Linux red hat installed on my system as virtual machine
i have already installed Load runner community edition on my windows host and i want to install it on Linux guest virtual machine
i red the guide bu got so lost with first 4 steps .. changing directory especially .. how and where to i have to change it ? i need alot of explain on this step

1. Kill any Load Runner agent process that may be running on the machine. Type:
   `cd /opt/HP/HP_LoadGenerator/bin;./m_daemon_setup -kill;su -;`
2. Change to super user.
3. If you have an earlier version of the load generator installed on the machine, you must first
   uninstall it. Type:
   `cd /opt/HP/HP_LoadGenerator/;cd _HP_LoadGenerator_Installation/;sh ./Change_HP_
   LoadGenerator_Installation;`
4. Change directory to //InstData/Linux/VM. The  is any path that contains the Web_Installers folder, for example /tmp/Web_
   Installers. Copy the installation folder to this location

Comment: You already asked this and I advise you to open a support case where one of our support staff will help you installing.

Comment: i tried to contact them but they don't support owners of free editions

Comment: change directory just means the "cd" command - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)

Comment: i know what cd means and does .. the problem i don't know where i have my directory to ?i need a clarify way to install loadrunner on linux

Comment: I don't know how else to help you. I cannot find the directory on your computer for you.